# Why is spark not repartioning my dataframe over multiple nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 128 cores, 8 nodes, 186Gb ram per node.

I have dataframe (Df) that I load from a jdbc source. It has one partition. I then call:

```
c = Df.repartition(128*3).cache().count()
```

The application web UI shows the cached rdd as having 384 partitions, but all located on one node (lets call it node 1) with a size of 57Mb in ram.

When I look at the count stages, I see 384 tasks, all executed on node 1.

Why does Spark not distribute the dataframe evenly on all the nodes?

I'm running this in pycharm. Here are the config values I set:

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("spark://sparkmaster:7087") \
        .appName(__SPARK_APP_NAME__) \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "80g") \
        .config("spark.eventlog.enabled", "True") \
        .config("spark.eventlog.dir", r"C:\Temp\Athena\UAT\Logs") \
        .config("spark.cores.max", 128) \
        .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "True") \
        .config("spark.executor.extraLibraryPath","/net/share/grid/bin/spark/UAT/bin/vertica-jdbc-8.0.0-0.jar") \
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Here are my spark properties

[image]

Comment: how do you submit/execute spark applications ? do you use yarn or spark standalone ?

Comment: Spark standalone cluster. My driver is located on a developer workstation. It has reasonable specs (12 cores, 64Gb ram)

Comment: can you provide your spark-submit command ?

Comment: Unfortunately my company does not like employees posting up code... :-(  Was there something specific you wanted to check?

Comment: After re-partitioning you also need to specify the number of executors, cores per executor and memory per executor to distribute the partition / tasks  in different nodes.

Comment: Ok, can you provide an example of the api call?

Comment: check the answer section.

Comment: Are you running it from any ide?

Comment: I have added the details to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this seems to be an optimisation. Simply calling repartition on a dataframe doesn't seem to cause it to distribute across nodes because spark decides that it isn't required to. Saves shuffle i guess...

Answer (score 1):

> here we specify the details of the resources and the application
>   details while submitting the application

```
./bin/spark-submit \
      --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
      --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
      --deploy-mode cluster \
      --supervise \
      --executor-memory 20G \
      --total-executor-cores 100 \
      /path/to/examples.jar \
```